# Android studio broken even with full reinstall

Tags: java, android, android-studio, compiler-errors, ide

I am getting the error messages

```
Error:Error: org.apache.xerces.dom.DocumentImpl cannot be cast to org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl
Possible causes for this unexpected error include:<ul><li>Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
<a href="syncProject">Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)</a></li><li>The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
<a href="stopGradleDaemons">Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)</a></li></ul>In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> C:\Users\User1\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\22.0.0\res\values\values.xml: Error: org.apache.xerces.dom.DocumentImpl cannot be cast to org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl
li>Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
<a href="syncProject">Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)</a></li><li>The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
<a href="stopGradleDaemons">Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)</a></li></ul>In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.
```

in Android Studio. It was working fine before until I started making some changes to the VM options under settings. Since then, I have uninstalled Android studio, deleting the folders under C:\users\user. When I create a new project, the same errors still comes up.

How can I fully remove Andriod studio so this error goes away?
I am thinking it's some registry setting. I really don't want to do a system reformat.